# Linked List program segmentation fault at fgets?

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault, fgets

It works fine the first time around. I can add an item, then display with the display function. But then when I try to add a second value, I get a seg fault as soon as I hit "a", right at fgets. Which I have commented out at the top.

(I haven't bothered with other functions except Add yet.)

```
#include    <stdio.h>
#include    <stdlib.h>
#include    <string.h>
#include    <ctype.h>
#include    "sortedll.h"

int     main(void)
{

int             intVal;
LNode           *headPtr = NULL;
char            buf[BUFLEN];
int             result;

do  {
    // ask the user what they want to do
    DisplayMenu();
    printf("Please enter a selection: ");
    fgets(buf, BUFLEN, stdin);
    *buf = toupper(*buf);
    switch (*buf)
        {
        case   'A':
            // prompt the user for a value; if we get one, add it to the
            // list
            printf("Please enter an integer value to add: ");
            fgets(buf, BUFLEN, stdin);

            //=======================================================================
            printf("check"); //doesn't print this second time around. seg fault at fgets?
            //=======================================================================

            if (1 != sscanf(buf, "%d", &intVal))
                {
                puts("Error reading the integer value...");
                }
            else
                {
                printf("1");
                headPtr = AddItem(headPtr, intVal);
                }
            break;

        case   'R':
            // if the list is empty display a message; else, get a value
            // from the user and attempt to remove it from the list
            if (NULL == headPtr)
                {
                puts("The list is currently empty...");
                }
            else
                {
                printf("Please enter an integer value to remove: ");
                fgets(buf, BUFLEN, stdin);
                if (1 != sscanf(buf, "%d", &intVal))
                    {
                    puts("Error reading the integer value...");
                    }
                else
                    {
                    headPtr = RemoveItem(headPtr, intVal);
                    }
                }
            break;

        case   'D':
            // display the current contents of the list
            result = DisplayList(headPtr);
            printf("Currently there %s %d node%s in the list.\n"
                                , (result != 1) ? "are" : "is"
                                , result
                                , (result != 1) ? "s" : "");
            break;

        case   'Q':
            // release all allocated memory and set the head pointer to
            // NULL to indicate that it is empty
            result = ReleaseMemory(headPtr);
            printf("There %s %d node%s released."
                                , (result != 1) ? "were" : "was"
                                , result
                                , (result != 1) ? "s" : "");
            headPtr = NULL;
            break;

        default:
            puts("Unrecognized option; please try again.");
            break;
        }
    puts(" ");

    } while ('Q' != *buf);

puts("Thanks for playing!  Bye!!\n");
return  0;

}  // end of "main"



// ==== AddItem ===============================================================


LNode*  AddItem(LNode  *headPtr, int  newItem)
{
    LNode *node = malloc(sizeof(*node));
    node->value = newItem;


    if(headPtr == NULL)
        {
        node->next = NULL;
        return node;
        }

    LNode *leadPtr = headPtr;
    LNode *trailPtr = headPtr;

    while(leadPtr->value != newItem)
        {
        leadPtr = leadPtr->next;
        trailPtr = leadPtr;
        }    

    leadPtr = leadPtr->next;
    free(trailPtr->next);    
    trailPtr->next = node;
    node->next = leadPtr;

    return headPtr;

}  // end of "AddItem"



// ==== DisplayList ===========================================================


int     DisplayList(LNode  *nodePtr)
{
    auto    int         counter = 0;

    // if the list is empty, indicate as such and return zero
    if (NULL == nodePtr)
        {
        puts("The list is currently empty...");
        return (0);
        }

    while (NULL != nodePtr)
        {
        printf("%d\n", nodePtr->value);
        nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
        counter++;
        }

    return (counter);

}  // end of "DisplayList"



// ==== DisplayMenu ===========================================================


void    DisplayMenu(void)
{
    puts("A)dd a value");
    puts("R)emove a value");
    puts("D)isplay the list");
    puts("Q)uit");

}  // end of "DisplayMenu"



// ==== ReleaseMemory =========================================================


int     ReleaseMemory(LNode  *headPtr)
{


}  // end of "ReleaseMemory"



// ==== RemoveItem ============================================================


LNode*  RemoveItem(LNode  *headPtr, int  targetItem)
{


}  // end of "RemoveItem"
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you'r trying to access leadPtr->value here when leadPtr might be NULL.

```
while(leadPtr->value != newItem)
    {
    leadPtr = leadPtr->next;
    trailPtr = leadPtr;
    }
```

You need to make sure that leadPtr != NULL before trying to access a member of it.

I'd recommend you to refactor the function that the code snippet belongs to, it looks a bit fragile in terms of memory access.

Comment: Well, I tried putting a printf check at the very beginning of the add function, and it seg faults before showing anything. So doesn't that mean it doesn't even enter the function before crashing? 

Even with the original check I wrote at around line 29, that doesn't show either. So it has to be the fgets right?

Comment: Whats the define of BUFLEN? Also, argument to toupper should be an unsigned char, otherwise it has undefined behaviour.

Comment: Also try to use different buffers for menu choice and value input. But first make sure you pass an `unsigned char` to `toupper()`. I think it's generally not recommended to have source and destination the same when calling functions like `toupper()`.

Comment: Sorry, buflen is 256. And, it still faults with unsigned char

Comment: First of: clear your local buffer `buf` with `memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf)` before you start using it. It's a function scope variable on the stack and contains random crap in memory before you clear it. I'd also recommend you to clear your buffer before every write to it.

Answer (score 0):

And you really ought to be checking the returns values from your malloc call:

LNode *node = malloc(sizeof(*node));

node->value = newItem;

What if you run out of heap space?

Comment: One should always do that yes. However it's very unlikely to be the answer to the problem.